# ClojureScript + momentjs (node.js) fails with .format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a")

Tags: node.js, leiningen, clojurescript, momentjs, cljsbuild

I'm trying to show current datetime format to console on node.js + clojure deploying [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) .

The working node js code:

```
var moment = require("./lib/moment/moment.js");
console.log(moment().format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"));
```

Console output:

```
$ node app1              
Friday, July 5th 2013, 9:57:07 am
```

so, I tried a clojureScript code as below:

```
(ns rxcljs.core
  (:use [cljs.nodejs :only [require]])
)
(def log #(.log js/console %))
(def moment (require "./lib/moment/moment.js"))

(->> (-> (moment) 
          (.format "dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a")
      )
     (log) 
 )
```

The Console output becomes

```
$ node app            
FridaynullundefinedJulyundefined5thundefined2013nullundefined9null56null31undefinedam
```

Datetime is partially presented with bunch of **null** and **undefined** for some reason.

Compiled js code:

```
var rxcljs = {core:{}};
rxcljs.core.log = function(a) {
  return console.log(a)
}; 
rxcljs.core.moment = cljs.nodejs.require.call(null, "./lib/moment/moment.js");
rxcljs.core.log.call(null, rxcljs.core.moment.call(null).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"));
```

The point the problem occurred looks not that problematic:

```
rxcljs.core.moment.call(null).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a")
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to a known incompatibility of Moment.js 2.0.0 with ClojureScript, fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/timrwood/moment/commit/340f7e3acb689d949755993cd5d33d217d97b2d9) by [David Altenburg](https://github.com/gensym). Here's the commit message:

> Format function now uses "instanceof" on a var rather than "typeof" on
>   that var's call to determine if the variable is a function.
>
> This fixes an incompatibility with ClojureScript, which defines
>   String.prototype.call as a function.

The version currently in the develop branch works fine.

Comment: Thank you for a very precise report. Impressive Michal.

Comment: FYI - This is included in the release of Moment.js 2.1.0.